# Count of how many times id occurs in table SQL regexp

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Hi I have a redshift table of articles that has a field on it that can contain many accounts. So there is a one to many relationship between articles to accounts.

However I want to create a new view where it lists the partner id's in one column and in another column a count of how many times the partner id appears in the articles table.

I've attempted to do this using regex and created a new redshift view, but am getting weird results where it doesn't always build properly. So one day it will say a partner appears 15 times, then the next 17, then the next 15, when the partner id count hasn't actually changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
SELECT partner_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM (SELECT id,
             partner_ids,
             SPLIT_PART(partner_ids,',',i) partner_id
      FROM positron_articles a
        LEFT JOIN util.seq_0_to_500 s
               ON s.i < regexp_count (partner_ids,',') + 2
               OR s.i = 1
      WHERE i > 0
      AND   regexp_count (partner_ids,',') = 0
      ORDER BY id)
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: You're saying `partner_ids` is a comma separated list of values?

Comment: correct Bozhidar, but see my comment below, looks like the problem wasn't with the above script but rather the app that exports the data to redshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with some of the more obvious things and see if we can start to glean other information.

Next `GROUP BY 1` on your outer query needs to be `GROUP BY partner_id`.

Next you don't need an `order by` in your `INNER` query and the database engine will probably do a better job optimizing performance without it so remove `ORDER BY id`.

If you want your final results to be ordered then add an `ORDER BY partner_id` or similar clause after your group by of your `OUTER` query.

It looks like there are also problems with how you are splitting a `partnerid` from `partnerids` but I am not positive about that because I need to understand your view and the data it provides to know how that affects your record count for `partnerid`.

Next your `LEFT JOIN` statement on the `util.seq_0_to_500` I am pretty sure you can drop off the `s.i = 1` as the first condition will satisfy that as well because `2` is `greater` than `1`.  However your `left join` really acts more like an `inner join` because you then exclude any non matches from `positron_articles` that don't have a `s.i > 0`.

Oddly then your entire join and `inner` query gets kind of discarded because you only want articles that have no commas in their `partnerids`: `regexp_count (partner_ids,',') = 0`

I would suggest posting the code for your `util.seq_0_to_500` and if you have a `partner table` let use know about that as well because you can probably get your answer a lot easier with that additional table depending on how regexp_count works.  I suspect `regex_count(partnerids,partnerid)` example`regex_count('12345,678',1234)` will return `greater` than `0` at which point you have no choice but to split the delimited strings into another table before counting or building a new matching function.

If regex_count only matches exact between commas and you have a partner table your query could be as easy as this:

```
SELECT
    p.partner_id
    ,COUNT(a.id) AS ArticlesAppearedIn
FROM
    positron_articles a
    LEFT JOIN PARTNERTABLE p
    ON regexp_count(a.partnerids,p.partnerid) > 0
GROUP BY
    p.partner_id
```

I will actually correct myself as I just thought of a way to join a partner table without `regexp_count`. So if you have a partner table this might work for you. If not you will need to split strings. It basically tests to see if the `partnerid` is the entire `partnerids`, at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end of `partnerids`.  If one of those is met then the records is returned.

```
SELECT
    p.partner_id
    ,COUNT(a.id) AS ArticlesAppearedIn
FROM
    PARTNERTABLE p
    INNER JOIN positron_articles a
    ON
       (
       CASE
          WHEN a.partnerids = CAST(p.partnerid AS VARCHAR(100)) THEN 1
          WHEN a.partnerids LIKE p.partnerid + ',%' THEN 1
          WHEN a.partnerids LIKE '%,' + p.partnerid + ',%' THEN 1
          WHEN a.partnerids LIKE '%,' + p.partnerid THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END
       ) = 1
GROUP BY
    p.partner_id
```

Comment: It actually looks like the problem wasn't with the query, but with the data export app. However, your comment was very helpful in understanding regex better so thank you!